# how to package a serialport class to dll in c#.net

Tags: c#, dll

i want to make a dll which would be used to communicate with my device and called by my program, so how to make it ?

```
public System.IO.Ports.SerialPort myport(string _pname)
    {
        string[] portList = System.IO.Ports.SerialPort.GetPortNames();
        if (portList.Length < 1)
            return null;
        else
        {
            SerialPort _port = new SerialPort(_pname);
            //SerialPort _port = portList[0];
            return _port;
        }
    }
```

i wrote this in my dll , but i have to use system.IO.Ports in my program.
how can it be made not to call this IO.ports?

Comment: What's the point of not having the reference directly? The framework dll still needs to be there. But you can encapsulate it if you don't want to see it directly.

Comment: @Alejandro i want to use this dll in my c++ program,  so i need the dll to complete all tasks serialport class have ,

Comment: The dll still doesn't performs any of the `SerialPort` functions, it just delegates to the framework class. Encapsulating it might remove the `using` statement, but the dependency is still there and your dll is still just  wrapper.

Comment: To clarify, the only choice is to have `SerialPort` being your dependency alongside the dll, or be a dependency of your dependency. The difference is "developer eye-candy" only, in practice. Unless you reimplement the whole `SerialPort` class instead of using it.

Comment: thanks @Alejandro,i got ur point,i would not like to reimplement the whole class